# RSpec test fails with "No route matches" for resources route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

### Context

I'm running into a very weird test failure that I can't explain based on my code.
When I run the spec test provided below, it will display the following error:

Failures:

1) GroupsController GET 'index' returns http success
     Failure/Error: get 'index'
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"groups"}
     # ./spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '

### Test case

The test case for the controller and routes set in RSpec looks like this:

```
describe GroupsController do

  before :each do
    @group = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

### Controller under test

I've written a very basic skeleton for my controller based on the test.
Currently it doesn't do a whole lot of stuff.

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @groups = current_user.groups
  end
end
```

### Routes configured to reach the controller

The routes.rb file looks like this:

```
NerdCooking::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :groups
  devise_for :users

  root :to => "home#welcome"
end
```

### Routes

```
              groups GET    /groups(.:format)              groups#index
                     POST   /groups(.:format)              groups#create
           new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)          groups#new
          edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)     groups#edit
               group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)          groups#show
                     PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)          groups#update
                     PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)          groups#update
                     DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)          groups#destroy
```

### Question

I have tried changing the route to get "groups" => "groups#index" instead of the resources route and that works, but it's not something I want since I want to use this as a RESTful service as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Update: Added the routes related to groups.

Comment: Can you do a `rake routes` and post the output?

Comment: Or if you are on Rails 4 you can just go to a web browser and enter a non-existant route and it will output all of your routes.

Comment: yes. `rake routes | grep groups` would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, apparently my Guard and Spork were acting mean.

Once I restarted Guard/Spork and it all worked as expected. Looking back at the code and configuration there was no reason why stuff was going wrong.

So if anyone else is experiencing this behavior and their config and code check out. Restart!

Comment: I was hoping it was something silly like this, but no such luck for me.

Comment: just had the same issue, all controller tests failing, all others passing.  tried restarting guard several times, turned out I needed to `spring stop` and then start guard again and all was ok once more.